# replace images in data from webservice android

Tags: android, web-services

Hi all,

```
  How can i replace the text or symbol from web service with local images in drawable folder.
```

I get a symbol and text from web service. I need to replace that symbol with my image that is saved in local drawable folder in the application.

Please suggest few ideas of how can i do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change or add any drawables inside your `drawable` folder. These resources are compiled into an `.apk` file, and there is no way to change them at runtime. Only solution I see is to store downloaded images on SD card and fetch them when you need it. Hope this helps.

Comment: I already have set of images. My issue is how can i replace the web service data symbol with a image . I get data as "Hi :)" . I need to replace this symbol with image before being displayed in Listview. Like Chat application. We select smiley and smiley is displayed.