# replace text with image, Data from .net web service android

Tags: android, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [replace images in data from webservice android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581027/replace-images-in-data-from-webservice-android)

can any one tell me how to display a image instead of a text. Text coming from web service.

Eg: I send "hi android". I need to replace text "android" with "icon.png" image.

How can i achieve this. Please help me in solving this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Exact dupe of at least 3 other questions made by you.

Answer (score 0):

Put an `ImageView` in your layout, set it's visibility as `gone` by default. When ever you are ready with your image, make the `textView` visibility `gone` and put the `ImageView` visibility to `visible` . Don't forget to set the `ImageView` resource before making it visible.

HTH.

Comment: can i do some thing like this. I shall create a image and refer that image and replace that with the text. Even then i need imageview to display. I am totally confused.